# error -- 'undefined local variable or method `arams' ', but I don't have arams in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I run ' rake test', I got this.

```
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `arams' for #<GuestsController:0x000055de0e4eee58>
```

Below it's the test method, which gives this error.

```
    test "should create guest" do
      assert_difference('Guest.count') do
      post event_guests_url(@event,@guest), params: {
           guest: {
             fullname: @guest.fullname,
             email: @guest.email,
             phonenumber: @guest.phonenumber
           }
         }
      end

     assert_redirected_to event_url(@event)
    end
```

I modified my code to this to what its the problem, but it still gave me the exactly same error.
Can someone give me some clues? Thank you.

```
    test "should create guest" do
      assert_difference('Guest.count') do
      post event_guests_url(@event,@guest)
      end

     assert_redirected_to event_url(@event)
    end
```

Comment: add your `guests_controller.rb` to your question

Comment: As the comment below states, I bet you misspelled `params` as `arams` somewhere.  Might be easiest to just do a full directory search for `arams` but it looks like it is in you `guests_controller.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a typo in your `guests_controller.rb` (the full error trace shohuld also contain a code location where you should start your search at)

But if the typo is already fixed - then make sure that you're editing the same sode that is running